# Find the number of rows after match found in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and expected output where I search for a value of `True` in the `balance` column.  Once found I use `balPrice` column value for that row and compare it with the `endPrice` column looking for the first instance where `endPrice` is lower than the `balPrice` and counts the number of rows from the `balance == True` row and the first instance found of a lower value row.  If no lower value is found then the row count is set to 0.

```
balance balPrice    endPrice
0   False   5.34    5.34
1   False   5.34    5.34
2   False   5.34    5.34
3   False   5.34    5.27
4   False   5.44    5.25
5   False   5.28    5.12
6   True    5.31    5.2
7   False   5.44    5.35
8   False   5.485   5.44
9   False   5.525   5.5
10  False   5.53    5.53
11  False   5.58    5.51
12  False   5.65    5.52
13  False   5.3     5.3
14  False   5.58    5.54
15  False   5.64    5.55
16  True    5.69    5.65
17  False   5.69    5.59
18  False   5.7     5.62
19  False   5.81    5.77
20  False   5.65    5.73
21  False   5.65    5.86
22  True    6.00    5.89
23  False   5.65    5.85
24  False   5.65    5.83
25  False   5.9     5.88
```

Here is what I tried which seems very convoluted.  Was looking for a better solution.

```
df_filtered = df[df.balance == True]
idx = []
for i in df_filtered.index:
    pos = np.where(df.endPrice[i+1:] <= df.balPrice[i])[0]
    if pos.size > 0:
        idx.append(pos[0]+1)
    else:
        idx.append(0)

df_filtered['numrows'] = idx
```

Expected Output:

```
balance balPrice    endPrice    numrows
True    5.31        5.2           7
True    5.69        5.65          1
True    6.00        5.89          1
```

Comment: please include the data as texts so we can copy them. [Images cannot be copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: How `numrows` is calculated is not clear comparing your sample code for `idx` elements and screenshot.

Comment: numrows is the number of row between the column that has balance == True to the first instance of the where the condition of the  endPrice column is less than or equal to the value of balPrice where balance == True.  The idx list is the first element of the np.where array where the condition is met.

Comment: you are right my bad i cut an pasted it incorrectly.